# If bash variable is 1 then run else do not

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I want to do something like this:

```
PROD=1

if [ "$PROD" -eq "1" ]
# Code
fi
```

I'm new to bash, but can anyone explain please why this code might fail? I am trying to only run that block of code if the variable PROD is defined as the value 1.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you forgot the `then`? It's not clear, since you leave out part of the code. Please show your complete code and tell us what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a correct syntax, only that you missed a `then` after the `if` condition:

```
PROD=1

if [ "$PROD" -eq "1" ]; then
        echo "yes"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do the following without '**if**'s and use curly braces:

```
var=1
[ $var -eq 1 ] && {
echo i am running
echo so far
echo ok
}
```

Note that you compare an integer value and not a string, the left and right side of the arithmetic binary operator of '**-eq**' should be a positive or negative integer. You can use '**=**' for string comparison.

Also, it is worth noting that the **[** character itself is a separate command, on *nix systems where there is no Bash available, you can use that if you like for the sake of portability. See on Ubuntu 13.10, for e.g.:

```
$ whatis [
[ (1)                - check file types and compare values
$ ls -l /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39560 Jan 17  2013 /usr/bin/[
```

Bash has its own builtin equivalent, though.

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
```